# How to sum data from specific record?

Tags: java, sql

```
    ___WORKER_ID___|_______OCCUR________
          20       |         1
          20       |         2
          21       |         3
          22       |         5
          20       |         1


    According to this table, I need to know each worker how many occur?
     Such as   Worker_id=20 has occur is 4   
               Worker_id=21 has occur is 8
```

I can get two value from this Worker table by this code

```
         String sql = "SELECT Table.worker_id,Table.occur FROM keyword_pages Table"
            + " WHERE keyword_id=" + PUID;

        conn = getConnection();
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int kwd_id = rs.getInt(1);    /**Worker_id is 20,20,21,22,20*/
            int occur = rs.getInt(2);     /**Worker_id is 1,2,3,5,1*/          

        }
```

How to get amount of occur for each worker?

This is my coding.
I use hashmap for store each record.
and store hashmap to linklist. But I haven't idea for get result.

```
  conn = getConnection();
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int kwd_id = rs.getInt(1);
            int occur = rs.getInt(2);
            hMap.put(kwd_id, occur);
            listID.add(hMap);
            //System.out.println(kwd_id +"  |  "+ occur);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listID.size(); i++) {


        }
```

Comment: A `Map<Integer,Integer>` lets you store integer counts for each worker ID.

Comment: `select worker_id, sum(occur) from keyword_pages group by worker_id`

Comment: Adding hMap repeatedly to listID isn't going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
String sql = "SELECT T.worker_id, SUM(T.occur) AS osum"
        + " FROM keyword_pages T"
        + " WHERE keyword_id=" + PUID
        + " GROUP BY T.worker_id";
```

Now `rs.getInt(2)` or `rs.getInt("osum")` will give the group's sum.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer,Integer> id2count = new HashMap<>();

while (rs.next()) {
        int kwd_id = rs.getInt(1);    /**Worker_id is 20,20,21,22,20*/
        int occur = rs.getInt(2);     /**Worker_id is 1,2,3,5,1*/          
   Integer count = id2count.get( kwd_id );
   if( count == null ){
       count = Integer.valueOf( 1 );
   } else {
       count += occur;
   }
   id2count.put( kwd_id, count );
}
```

** Later **

Code to retrieve and print the accumulated values:

```
for( Integer key: id2count.keySet() ){
    System.out.println( key + ": " + id2count.get(key) );
}
```

Comment: Integer count = id2count.get( kwd_id );

something wrong. it go to cath(Exception)

Comment: This code is absolutely correct. Did you copy it correctly? If there is a NullPointerException: did you initialize id2count properly?